# Using tfrecords with pairs of images (siamese model)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm updating my code to use tfrecords to speed up (hopefully) a siamese model training. Based one .csv with pairs of images, I created tfrecords with the following code:

```
from data_generation.tf_records_helper import image_feature, int64_feature
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math


def create_example(image1: np.ndarray, image2: np.ndarray, label: int) -> tf.train.Example:
    """
    Creates a single tf train example.

    Args:
        image1: first image in the pair.
        image2: second image in the pair.
        label: label of the example.

    Returns:
        tf train example.
    """
    feature = {
        "image1": image_feature(image1),
        "image2": image_feature(image2),
        "label": int64_feature(label),
    }
    return tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))


def read_data(training_df_path: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Reads a data frame containing positive/negative pairs of images.

    Args:
        training_df_path: path to the split file.

    Returns:
        Data frame with training data information.
    """
    df = pd.read_csv(training_df_path)
    # region testing
    sample_len = int(len(df.sample(n=2006, random_state=42)) / 2)
    df_p = df[df["label"] == "positive"].sample(n=sample_len, random_state=42)
    df_n = df[df["label"] == "negative"].sample(n=sample_len, random_state=42)
    df = pd.concat([df_p, df_n], axis=0)
    # endregion
    label_map = {"positive": 1, "negative": 0}
    df["label"] = df["label"].map(lambda x: label_map.get(x))
    df = df.sample(frac=1)  # to prevent df to be ordered by pos/neg samples
    return df


def df_to_tf_records(training_df_path: str, num_samples: int = 1000, tfrecords_dir: str = "/dataset") -> None:
    df = read_data(training_df_path)
    num_tf_records = math.ceil(len(df) / num_samples)
    print(f"# tf records = {num_tf_records}.")
    for tfrec_num in range(num_tf_records):
        samples = df.iloc[(tfrec_num * num_samples) : ((tfrec_num + 1) * num_samples)]

        with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(
            tfrecords_dir + "/file_%.2i-%i.tfrec" % (tfrec_num, len(samples))
        ) as writer:
            for i, sample in samples.iterrows():
                image1_path = sample["img_path_x"]
                image2_path = sample["img_path_y"]
                label = sample["label"]

                image1 = tf.io.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(image1_path))
                image2 = tf.io.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(image2_path))
                example = create_example(image1, image2, label)
                writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

My generator looks like this:

```
"""
Custom data generator for Siamese model with contrastive loss.
"""


from typing import Optional
import tensorflow as tf


AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE


class CustomDataset:
    """
    Creates data sets from a data frame.

    Attributes:
        tf_records_dir: path to the tf records.
        batch_size: batch size.
        input_size: network input size.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        tf_records_dir: str = "/dataset",
        batch_size: Optional[int] = 32,
        input_size: Optional[tuple[int, int, int]] = (224, 224, 3),
    ):
        """
        Args:
            tf_records_dir: path to the tf records.
            batch_size: batch size.
            input_size: network input size.
        """
        self.train_filenames = tf.io.gfile.glob(f"{tf_records_dir}/*.tfrec")
        self.input_size: tuple[int, int, int] = input_size
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    @staticmethod
    def _parse_tfrecord_fn(example):
        feature_description = {
            "image1": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            "image2": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            "label": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        }
        example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, feature_description)
        example["image1"] = tf.io.decode_jpeg(example["image1"], channels=3)
        example["image2"] = tf.io.decode_jpeg(example["image2"], channels=3)
        return example

    def _prepare_sample(self, features):
        image1 = tf.image.resize(features["image1"], size=self.input_size[:2])
        image2 = tf.image.resize(features["image2"], size=self.input_size[:2])
        return image1, image2, features["label"]

    def get_dataset(self) -> tf.data.Dataset:
        """
        Creates a data set from positive/negative pairs of images.
        """
        options = tf.data.Options()
        options.experimental_deterministic = False

        dataset = (
            tf.data.TFRecordDataset(self.train_filenames, num_parallel_reads=AUTOTUNE)
            .map(self._parse_tfrecord_fn, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
            .map(self._prepare_sample, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
            .shuffle(self.batch_size * 10)
            .batch(self.batch_size)
            .prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
        )
        dataset = dataset.with_options(options)

        return dataset
```

When training the model, I  get:

```
    /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py:199 assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError('Layer ' + layer_name + ' expects ' +

    ValueError: Layer model expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 224, 224, 3) dtype=float32>]
```

The big change I see in the generator is that I'm not using

```
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip(
        (positive_dataset, negative_dataset, label)
    )
```

anymore. I think the issue may be related to that, cause now I have one tensor with two inputs (?) but I'm not sure how to properly pass this data to the model, which looks like this:

```
def create_model(
    target_shape: Optional[tuple[int, int, int]] = (224, 224, 3),
    path: Optional[str] = None,
) -> Model:
    """
    Creates the siamese model.

    Args:
        target_shape: image dimensions.
        path: path to best weights.

    Returns:
        Siamese model.
    """
    input_1 = layers.Input(shape=target_shape, name="inp_1")
    input_2 = layers.Input(shape=target_shape, name="inp_2")

    img_augmentation = get_augmentation_layer()
    input = layers.Input(shape=target_shape, name="input")
    lambda_1 = layers.Lambda(
        lambda image: tf.keras.applications.efficientnet.preprocess_input(image),
        name="pre_process",
    )(img_augmentation(input))
    base_cnn = EfficientNetB0(
        weights="imagenet",
        input_tensor=lambda_1,
        input_shape=target_shape,
        include_top=False,
    )
    # CONV/FC -> BatchNorm -> ReLu(or other activation) -> Dropout -> CONV/FC ->
    pool = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(base_cnn.output)
    flatten = layers.Flatten(name="base_output_flatten")(pool)
    dense1 = layers.BatchNormalization(name="dense1_norm")(flatten)
    dense1 = layers.Dense(4096, activation="relu", name="dense1")(dense1)
    dense1 = layers.Dropout(0.3, name="dense1_dropout")(dense1)
    dense2 = layers.BatchNormalization(name="dense2_norm")(dense1)
    dense2 = layers.Dense(1024, activation="relu", name="dense2")(dense2)
    dense2 = layers.Dropout(0.2, name="dense2_dropout")(dense2)
    output = layers.Dense(512, name="dense_output")(dense2)

    embedding = Model(input, output, name="Embedding")

    tower_1 = embedding(input_1)
    tower_2 = embedding(input_2)

    merge_layer = layers.Lambda(l1_distance, name="l1")([tower_1, tower_2])
    normal_layer = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="l1_norm")(merge_layer)
    comparison_layer = layers.Dense(
        1,
        activation="sigmoid",
        name="final_layer",
    )(normal_layer)
    siamese = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=comparison_layer)

    if path is not None:
        siamese.load_weights(path)

    return siamese
```

Comment: What are the shapes of one entry in `dataset`?

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anybody, I was able to fix it replacing:

```
def _prepare_sample(self, features):
    image1 = tf.image.resize(features["image1"], size=self.input_size[:2])
    image2 = tf.image.resize(features["image2"], size=self.input_size[:2])
    return image1, image2, features["label"]
```

by

```
def _prepare_sample(self, features):
    image1 = tf.image.resize(features["image1"], size=self.input_size[:2])
    image2 = tf.image.resize(features["image2"], size=self.input_size[:2])
    images = {"inp_1": image1, "inp_2": image2}
    return images, features["label"]
```

Using the names of my two inputs.